# How to get attached files outputted by views for given node id (programatically)

Tags: views, files

I am working with a module.
I have a node id. That node id is a page and it has 2 or more view blocks on it. The results of views are lists of nodes with file attachments.

I need to get all the files attached to the nodes outputted by the view on this particular page.

I work in a module file and I can supply the nid of type page where these views sit.

I could not find much help so I decided to ask for what would be the best way to approach this.

I am new to Drupal so I will appreciate a great explanation on how to approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I'd come back and explain my solution. It involves a series of loops through the following: getting regions available for current nid, then the blocks displayed on that nid, then loading each view that has blocks on that nid to obtain access to the fields. I can't provide any code but in theory that's what it involves.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to let people know how you solved your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I had some fields for related documents, and so I added those in a custom field (HTML format to link to my already uploaded documents), and created a view block in the sidebar to grab these fields from the current node. I went [here](http://mediatribe.net/en/node/21) and did what this guy said:

That worked for me.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Drupal Answers. May you expand your answer with a summary of what said in the linked page?